# Print line numbers of files I am searching through

Tags: bash, text-processing

I am looking for a way to print the line number of files my script is going through.  I have found `$LINENO` but when I do

`echo 'Found foo in file' $(basename $foo) 'on line' $LINENO >> foo.csv`

It prints the results "Found foo in file Foo on line 97 in the `.csv` file.  I would like it to print the line in the file it is looking at and not the line the script it is on.  How can I echo the line number in the files?

Comment: what are you using to iterate through the lines of the file?

Comment: I am using an `if then`.

Comment: Could you show us the entire loop? That way we can give you a solution tailored to your needs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `nl` to number the lines of the file before going through them:

```
$ cat testfile
a
b
c
$ nl -b a testfile
   1 a
   2 b
   3 c
```

Note that `-b a` is required because, by default, `nl` doesn't number blank lines.

Of course, this will be inefficient if your file is very large as it will go through the file twice.

Perhaps a better alternative is to use your own line counter so that you need only go through the file once:

```
COUNT=0
while read -r line; do
    COUNT=$(( $COUNT + 1 ))
    if [ ... ];then
        # Do things to the line
        # Make use of COUNT to show line number
    fi
done < your_file_here
```

This will only work if you're processing the file line-by-line. It won't work if you're using `grep` for example.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy - there's an infinite supply of these 8-)

Comment: It doesn't count empty lines even if I use option `$ nl -ba app.d`. If I add a white space the line is counted. That tool isn't that great.

Answer (score 2):

The way I've found to do this is to use `trap DEBUG` to store current line number to a secondary variable **and** `trap ERR` to dump them:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'LASTLINENO=$_LINENO;_LINENO=$LINENO' DEBUG
trap 'echo ERROR in file" $(basename $0) on line $LASTLINENO" >>logfile' ERR

echo test
test echo
bla
```

This will print on console:

```
test
./test.bash: line 8: bla: command not found
```

and store on *logfile*:

```
ERROR in file test.bash on line 8
```

For showing script:

```
cat -n test.bash
     1      #!/bin/bash
     2
     3      trap 'LASTLINENO=$_LINENO;_LINENO=$LINENO' DEBUG
     4      trap 'echo ERROR in file" $(basename $0) on line $LASTLINENO"' ERR
     5
     6      echo test
     7      test echo
     8      bla
```

And for showing desired (corrupted) line:

```
sed -ne 8p <test.bash
bla
```